# Caffe: libcaffe.a is not really linked when trying whole-archive

Tags: gcc, linker, g++, caffe

#### Issue summary

I am trying to link Caffe static library (`libcaffe.a`) to my project, but I want to link it using the command `-Wl,--whole-archive`. The issue is that after `ldd -d mylib.so` it shows a lot of `undefined symbol` from Caffe, as if the `libcaffe.a` wasn't really linked to `mylib.so`.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Create a docker container with Ubuntu 18.04 minimal
2. apt-get update
3. apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev protobuf-compiler libprotobuf-dev libgflags-dev libgoogle-glog-dev libopenblas-dev libboost-dev libboost-all-dev
4. git clone —branch 1.0 https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git
5. cd caffe
6. mkdir build
7. cd build
8. cmake -DBLAS=open ..
9. make all
10. copy libcaffe.a to my project's lib directory
11. go to my project build dir
12. cmake ..
13. make
14. ldd -d mylib.so

#### Tried solutions

I tried to use another version of gcc/g++, but I found another problem that I've reported [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/6784)

#### System configuration

- Operating system: Ubuntu 18.04
- Compiler: gcc/g++ 7
- CUDA version (if applicable): OFF
- CUDNN version (if applicable): OFF
- BLAS: OpensBLAS 0.2.20
- Python version (if using pycaffe): OFF
- MATLAB version (if using matcaffe): OFF

#### My CMakeLists.txt to generate `mylib.so`

**EDIT 01 :** Also `whole-archive` libproto.a I didn't try it earlier, because It was never necessary to include this lib before. Maybe there is relation to my current ubuntu configuration, gcc/g++ version and libs versions

**EDIT 02 :** Changed the libs linking order, `linking boost_thread` after `libcaffe.a` and `libproto.a`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(mylib)

SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE OFF)

add_definitions(-DCPU_ONLY=1 -std=c++11 -fPIC -m64)

SET (CAFFE_INCLUDE  /mypath/caffe/include/)
SET (PROTO_INCLUDE  /mypath/caffe/build/include/)

SET (DEP_LIBS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../libs)
SET (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../libs")

include_directories(${CAFFE_INCLUDE} ${PROTO_INCLUDE})

add_library(
    mylib SHARED
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mycode.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
    mylib
    -Wl,--whole-archive ${DEP_LIBS}/libcaffe.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
    -Wl,--whole-archive ${DEP_LIBS}/libproto.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
    ${DEP_LIBS}/libboost_thread.so.1.65.1
    ${DEP_LIBS}/libprotobuf.so.10
    ${DEP_LIBS}/libglog.so.0
    )
```

#### Terminal output after step 8

```
The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - found
Looking for pthread_create
Looking for pthread_create - not found
Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
Looking for pthread_create in pthread
Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
Found Threads: TRUE  
Boost version: 1.65.1
Found the following Boost libraries:
  system
  thread
  filesystem
  chrono
  date_time
  atomic
Found GFlags: /usr/include  
Found gflags  (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgflags.so)
Found Glog: /usr/include  
Found glog    (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so)
Found Protobuf: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so;-lpthread (found version "3.0.0") 
Found PROTOBUF Compiler: /usr/bin/protoc
HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine C configuration
HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine CXX configuration
Found HDF5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_cpp.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so (found version "1.10.0.1") found components:  HL 
CUDA is disabled. Building without it...
Found OpenBLAS libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblas.so
Found OpenBLAS include: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
Python interface is disabled or not all required dependencies found. Building without it...
Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.17.1") 

******************* Caffe Configuration Summary *******************
General:
  Version           :   1.0.0
  Git               :   1.0-dirty
  System            :   Linux
  C++ compiler      :   /usr/bin/c++
  Release CXX flags :   -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
  Debug CXX flags   :   -g -fPIC -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
  Build type        :   Release

  BUILD_SHARED_LIBS :   OFF
  BUILD_python      :   OFF
  BUILD_matlab      :   OFF
  BUILD_docs        :   OFF
  CPU_ONLY          :   ON
  USE_OPENCV        :   OFF
  USE_LEVELDB       :   OFF
  USE_LMDB          :   OFF
  USE_NCCL          :   OFF
  ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK :   OFF

Dependencies:
  BLAS              :   Yes (open)
  Boost             :   Yes (ver. 1.65)
  glog              :   Yes
  gflags            :   Yes
  protobuf          :   Yes (ver. 3.0.0)
  CUDA              :   No

Install:
  Install path      :   /mypath/caffe/build/install

Configuring done
Generating done
Build files have been written to: /mypath/caffe/build
```

#### Terminal output after step 14

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff869d5000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /home/shared-folder/dev/cppsaffe/../libs/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7d10862000)
libm.so.6 => /home/shared-folder/dev/cppsaffe/../libs/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7d104c4000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /home/shared-folder/dev/cppsaffe/../libs/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7d102ac000)
libc.so.6 => /home/shared-folder/dev/cppsaffe/../libs/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7d0febb000)
libboost_thread.so.1.65.1 => /home/shared-folder/dev/cppsaffe/../libs/libboost_thread.so.1.65.1 (0x00007f7d0fc8d000)
libboost_system.so.1.65.1 => /home/shared-folder/dev/cppsaffe/../libs/libboost_system.so.1.65.1 (0x00007f7d0fa88000)
libprotobuf.so.10 => /home/shared-folder/dev/cppsaffe/../libs/libprotobuf.so.10 (0x00007f7d0f5c5000)
libglog.so.0 => /home/shared-folder/dev/cppsaffe/../libs/libglog.so.0 (0x00007f7d0f390000)
libgflags.so.2.2 => /home/shared-folder/dev/cppsaffe/../libs/libgflags.so.2.2 (0x00007f7d0f16b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7d1110f000)
librt.so.1 => /home/shared-folder/dev/cppsaffe/../libs/../libs/librt.so.1 (0x00007f7d0ef63000)
libpthread.so.0 => /home/shared-folder/dev/cppsaffe/../libs/../libs/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7d0ed44000)
libz.so.1 => /home/shared-folder/dev/cppsaffe/../libs/../libs/libz.so.1 (0x00007f7d0eb27000)
libunwind.so.8 => /home/shared-folder/dev/cppsaffe/../libs/../libs/libunwind.so.8 (0x00007f7d0e90b000)
liblzma.so.5 => /home/shared-folder/dev/cppsaffe/../libs/../libs/../libs/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f7d0e6e4000)
libdl.so.2 => /home/shared-folder/dev/cppsaffe/../libs/../libs/../libs/../libs/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7d0e4e0000)
undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe14ScaleParameter17default_instance_E (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZTIN5caffe16V1LayerParameterE    (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZTIN5caffe9BlobProtoE    (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZTIN5caffe9BlobShapeE    (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe18ParameterParameter17default_instance_E (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe16ReshapeParameter17default_instance_E   (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe19WindowDataParameter19_default_crop_mode_B5cxx11E   (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe18RecurrentParameter17default_instance_E (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe20ConvolutionParameter17default_instance_E   (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe14PReLUParameter17default_instance_E (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe16V1LayerParameter17default_instance_E   (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe13BiasParameter17default_instance_E  (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZTIN5caffe12NetStateRuleE    (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe15SolverParameter14_default_type_B5cxx11E    (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe14EmbedParameter17default_instance_E (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe21InnerProductParameter17default_instance_E  (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe15FillerParameter14_default_type_B5cxx11E    (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe14LayerParameter17default_instance_E (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZTIN5caffe9ParamSpecE    (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe12NetParameter17default_instance_E   (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe16V0LayerParameter17default_instance_E   (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe9BlobProto17default_instance_E   (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe15SolverParameter17default_instance_E    (./libcppsaffe.so)
undefined symbol: _ZTIN5caffe14LayerParameterE  (./libcppsaffe.so)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited my question **EDIT 01** and **EDIT 02** with the solution.